# Why my span element contains 5 text nodes?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

It's a bit odd thing, but I will try my best to explain.

I have this span:

[image: Text content of it doesn't really matter. Same case if it's empty]

When I log .childNodes, I get this:

[image]

But only one node contains the text that was in span:

[image]

Other nodes look like this:

[image]

So, how can I tell which node is "my" node? If I put some content in any other node but "right" node, the text content won't render at all.

BTW, .normalize() does the trick, but has some unwanted side-effects, so I wish there is another way around. Also, I am using Vue and I guess the problem might be deep inside of it, however I'm not sure.

Comment: I'd try to write code such that this wouldn't be something to worry about - for example, to just assign to the `.textContent` of the (parent) element instead

Comment: @CertainPerformance I think I can't do this in my case. I missed the part where I should've said that I need the text node for creating selection range, my bad. Without text node I can't do that

Comment: Screenshots of the console are pretty hard to read. Can you post source code as text, please? See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). Thanks.

Comment: Why are you getting so many nodes in the first place? How are you querying those nodes? I don't know how is this built but maybe you are not adding enough specificity in the query? or maybe you have different instances of the same element that you are not aware of... It is very hard to tell if you don't provide a code snippet or some minimal reproducible steps.

Answer (score 0):

There could be whitespace or hidden characters  in that `span` that are being returned as `text` nodes, but that you cannot see rendered to the screen.

How is the content of the `span` being generated?

Can you add a child `span` to `span.line` and add content directly to that?